# replacing use of one def with other def in llvm IR

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I have following IR:

```
%2 = load i32* %b, align 4
store i32 %2, i32* %a, align 4
%3 = load i32* %a, align 4
store i32 %3, i32* %b, align 4
```

which is essentially

```
a=b; b=a;
```

Now, after copy propagation, i want something like:

```
a=b; b=b;
```

So, I do this:

```
i->setOperand(0,op1)  //op1 points to %b, i points to  [%3 = load i32* %a, align 4]
i->replaceUsesOfWith(op2,op1); //op2 points to %a
```

Doing this, I get into infinite loop for above IR. So I have a feeling that there is some problem with removing i from uses of op1 and adding i to uses of op2.
However, code runs fine for something like:

```
a=b; c=a;
```

after transformation I get: `a=b; c=b;`

Comment: I don't know why it hangs, but I'm certain that your code doesn't do what you think it does. Specifically, `i->setOperand(0,op1)` and `i->replaceUsesOfWith(op2,op1)` do the same thing in this context, so there's no sense in calling both of them.

Comment: yup, I removed setOperand() and same result.
But, the point is how do I remove instruction i from uses of op2 after I've replaced op2 with op1 in i.
(I also tried ReplaceInstWithInst but same infinite loop)

Answer (score 1):

ReplaceInstWithInst() does the job, problem was when op1 and op2 both points to same operand it keep replacing and goes into infinite loop. So, just had to add one check op1 != op2